# A simple Hello World written in C does not output anything when using external library function

Tags: c, windows, pcre

Actualy, i have to debug an old C program. I'm a noob at C programming and i'm facing a strange behaviour when running this program. This program use PCRE, a regular expression library ported to Windows (i got the "developer files" from http://gnuwin32.sourceforge.net/downlinks/pcre-lib-zip.php) but when the program try to use a function from this library the main method isn't even called.
I've narrowed it down to a simple HelloWorld as you can see below:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <regex.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    printf("Hello, world!\n");
    regex_t re;
    regcomp(&re,"sam", 0);
    return 0;
}
```

This program compile and link successfuly.

```
19:55:32 **** Rebuild of configuration Debug for project Test ****
Info: Internal Builder is used for build
gcc "-ID:\\Cpp\\pcre\\include" -O0 -g3 -Wall -c -fmessage-length=0 -o Hello.o "..\\Hello.c" 
gcc "-LD:\\Cpp\\pcre\\lib" -o Test.exe Hello.o -lpcre -lpcreposix 

19:55:35 Build Finished. 0 errors, 0 warnings. (took 3s.750ms)
```

When executed it returns 0 and nothing is printed even if the printf call is the first call of the main function

If i comment the call to regcomp:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <regex.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    printf("Hello, world!\n");
    regex_t re;
    //regcomp(&re,"sam", 0);
    return 0;
}
```

Then compile and link

```
19:57:19 **** Rebuild of configuration Debug for project Test ****
Info: Internal Builder is used for build
gcc "-ID:\\Cpp\\pcre\\include" -O0 -g3 -Wall -c -fmessage-length=0 -o Hello.o "..\\Hello.c" 
..\Hello.c: In function 'main':
..\Hello.c:12:10: warning: unused variable 're' [-Wunused-variable]
   12 |  regex_t re;
      |          ^~
gcc "-LD:\\Cpp\\pcre\\lib" -o Test.exe Hello.o -lpcre -lpcreposix 

19:57:21 Build Finished. 0 errors, 1 warnings. (took 2s.400ms)
```

When running the program it returns 0 and print as expected:

```
Hello, world!
```

Can someone help me understand what happen under the hood and successfully execute this regcomp function?

Comment: What error code does function `regcomp()` return?

Comment: it looks like UB. Have you tried to step into `regcomp` in the debugger or you don't have the source files for the lib?

Comment: You are not using the compiled regular expression.  `regcomp` “compiles” a regular expression into a `regex_t` data structure that you can use with `regexec` to match against a string

Comment: When the function regcomp is uncommented, main is not called so : no debug possible and no error. That is THE problem

Comment: What happens when you run your program in a debugger?

Comment: No debug possible, the main function is not called

Comment: So you're saying that your program does not compile?

Comment: No, compilation and linking are successfull for the two cases

Comment: Well, your main function is running, it's just not outputting anything.  There could be a number of reasons for that; most likely it is because your call to `regcomp` is failing.  You can prove that the printf is executing by flushing the output buffer right after calling the `printf` : `fflush(stdout);`

Comment: Have a look here: https://repl.it/@robertwharvey/WealthyMediumFrontpage#main.c

Comment: The fflush did not help. Even a breakpoint on the printf call is not working. The breakpoint works as expected when regcomp is commented

Comment: I realize your using windows, but, under linux, you have to include either `pcre.h` [or `pcre2.h`] to get the pcre definitions. Actually, the needed files are `pcreposix.h` or `pcre2posix.h` Otherwise, you get the GNU version [which is in `glibc`]. I'm wondering if that's an issue for you. Under linux, the program works fine with `regex.h` [GNU] and with `pcreposix.h` with `-lpcre`

Comment: The binary i downloaded contains in the include folder only regex.h, pcre.h and pcreposix.h. regex.h includes both pcre.h and pcreposix.h. The lib directory contains the following files libpcre.dll.a libpcreposix.dll.a pcre-bcc.lib pcre.lib pcre3.dll.def pcreposix-bcc.lib pcreposix.lib pcreposix3.dll.def. I'm linking with library pcre and pcreposix, maybe i'm wrong here?